# How can I activate notification (with sound) after Run is finished on IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, audio, notifications

I usually go on to do other things while the project is compiling. I would like to know if there's a way to get a sound notification when the run is finished.

I tried looking into the Setting -> Appearance & Behaviour -> Notifications but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was already [reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270145/), but it seems it's not yet implemented. Maybe you can leave an upvote. Possible workaround is to use this third-party [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6100-console-beep).